# What is the proper way to unit test .NET Core Web Application?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I'm new at web development (used to develop desktop apps). I didn't manage to find a proper way to unit test internals of my web application.

Let's say I do have a Foo class which do have a strictly defined behaviour (completely independed from DB and/or UI). I need to make sure that my implementation is corrent. In the desktop app I just add another test dll with unit tests (if the class is public) or just internal class with tests. And start it with nunit to make sure that it works. But how is should be done in the web application?

The only way I can think of is to add some debug-only pages on which I will run my test and ignore them during the deploy. But I think there should be some unit test framework for that and I just didn't manage to find it.

Do the .net core web developers have any standard way to do it (something like nunit)?

Comment: "In the desktop app I just add another test dll with unit tests (if the class is public) or just internal class with tests." - What prevents you from doing this with `ApiController`s?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/testing/unit-testing-with-dotnet-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the recommended unit testing framework to use with .NET Core apps is called Xunit. You can read an overview and walkthrough [here](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dotnet-core).

Comment: `The original content from this page is now outdated. Visual Studio 2017 includes built-in support xUnit.net projects, as does dotnet new. New content will be added here when the new .NET CLI SDK runner is available. `

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. This is the correct answer.